# Get price between like 0-5000 and 50001-10000 from price column?

Tags: php, mysql

i have price column in product table from that column i want get price between like 0-5000 and 5001-1000.is it possible in MySQL?

```
4999.00
9990.00
10990.00
12990.00
11499.00
17000.00
10990.00
12999.00
14200.00
19499.00
20999.00
```

Comment: so You want two queries? Or One ? And what about 5000-5001 ?

Comment: Assuming you mean 10000, then yes. It's perfectly possible

Comment: What have you tried and what would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1):

Using between:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab_name
WHERE price BETWEEN 0 and 5000;
   -- price BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000
```